# How I can product only 1 time random value

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to product random value only one time and if I product it inside a function, whenever I call function, x variable changes due to Random method runs again and create new value.

Than I create a global variable and assigned random method to it. In this time random method run 1 time and value of global variable keeps same. But I want to define the range depend on input. In this case I can not take user input before random method runs.

So what should I do?
User should define range of random but x variable should take only one time value.

Because I will use this x variable inside another method.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jscss.css" />
</head>
<script>var size = document.getElementById("size"); var x = Math.floor(Math.random(size) * (5)) + 1; function afunc() { alert(x); }</script>
<body>
    <input type="number" id="size"><br /> <button onclick="afunc()">Submit</button><br />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Initialize the variable with false or null, and then inside your click handler function, assign a random value to it, _if_ it is still false/null.

Comment: Is it possible to write it here?

Comment: `var x = null; function afunc() { if(x === null) { x = Math.floor(…); } /*rest of function here*/; }`

Answer (score 1):

```js
var x;
function changeSize(){
  var size = document.getElementById("size").value; 
  x = Math.floor(Math.random(size) * (5)) + 1; 
  console.log("size:",size,"X:",x);
}
function afunc() { alert(x); }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="number" id="size" onchange="changeSize();"><br /> 
<button onclick="afunc()">Submit</button><br />
```

Edit: for variable `x` load only one time

```js
var x;
function changeSize(){
  var size = document.getElementById("size").value; 
  if(!x){
    x = Math.floor(Math.random(size) * (5)) + 1; 
  }
  console.log("size:",size,"X:",x);
}
function afunc() { alert(x); }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<input type="number" id="size" onchange="changeSize();"><br /> 
<button onclick="afunc()">Submit</button><br />
```

Comment: Thanks for quick comment. But it still does not work. Because when we enter value inside changesize() function, it does not effect global variable value and I took alert as undefined.

Comment: When I use below code and click button x variable keeps changes due to I call changesize() function again again and give new value to x. But I need 1 stable value.



>var x;
>function changeSize(){
  >var size = document.getElementById("size").value; 
  >x = Math.floor(Math.random(size) * (5)) + 1; 
>}
>function afunc() { 
>changeSize();
>alert(x); }

Comment: yes you have to click the submit button or other that define the `onchange`.

Comment: one question, do you need load the `x` value only one (first time)? if yes then your `size` also need one tiem.